# data processing through java collections dealing with million of records.

Tags: java, collections

I want to get a large amount of data in a java collection, returned from a query on a nosql database. The scenario is I am using cassandra for my research work, there is a situation where i have to do a query on cassandra, and it will return with 5 million records and than i have to query on some other database for example neo4j with those 5 million records and it will return me the final result set. how can i get 5 million data records in any collection in java, and what will be best efficient solution in this case ? . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And why do you assume 5 million is hitting any kind of limitation? Each and every Java collection can accommodate that much and then some, the only limitation is heap size.

Comment: i have 100 million records in the cassandra database, i will run some query that will filter the data and give me at-least 5 million records. I want java to deal with these large number of records with minimum usage of memory.

Comment: What will use the memory are the query results, not the collection's internals. Unless you're retrieving nothing but `Integer`s or similar.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for your reply. any other solution do you recommend for this situation ?

Comment: The natural approach would be to not retrieve all elements at once, but receive them in chunks, then issue a query to the second database for each chunk separately.

Comment: that will be the best solution, but in my case i have to fetch all the records at one time to log the query running time.

Comment: Then I don't see what "other solution" you may be expecting. If you want to retrieve all elements into a single Java collection, then that's your solution.

Comment: retrieving results in to a pipe delimited string in file system ? just a thought . any ways thanks @MarkoTopolnik :)

Comment: If you dump to the filesystem, then again it will influence your query timing.

Comment: yes that would be the case. lets see,  i have to do it one way or another.